# How to compile all dependencies with browserify?

Tags: javascript, browserify

I am trying to learn how to use browserify so I can compile all my dependencies to one file. All the dependencies are being pulled in with NPM through updating a package.json. For example, I want to create a file with browserify that consists of the compiled javascript from this json file.

```
"dependencies": {
   "highcharts": "0.0.11",
   "bootstrap": "3.1.0"
}
```

I would like to do this on the fly and have it automatically pull from this json file.

Comment: So I understand correctly, are you trying to make `browserify` read the contents of `package.json` and produce a vendor bundle that just includes all of your dependencies?

Comment: @Mathletics exactly. I know there is require('') but I feel like than I would have to hard code the dependencies, which I don't want.

Comment: Well, the file that uses either of these should explicitly `require` it.

Comment: I don't think you can (or _should_) do what you're trying to do.

Comment: did you get into a conclusion about this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `require` the dependencies in whatever module you need them. For example, if one of your dependencies is Lodash, you'll `require` it where you use it:

```
var lodash = require('lodash');

module.exports = function() {
  // do something with lodash in here if you want
};
```

The purpose of using something like browserify, webpack, etc., is that you specifically **don't** compile everything into a "global dependency bundle", as this subverts the modularization that those libraries (browserify, webpack) are meant to impose.

Comment: Is this an answer to the question?